# Fetch eagerly lazy defined relations

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a complex data structure and at the moment we are fetching everything eagerly using Hibernate,

Due to the charges that this fetch type impose to the server and also the fact that the front-end part of the project doesn't always need all the information but only the parent object information, we would like to pass everything to a lazy type fetch but sometimes, an eager type will be needed,

Is there a way to fetch data eagerly only sometimes using hibernate?

I could do that with a named query, but I would like to know first if it's feasible with Hibernate

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force eager load of selected properties using `CriteriaApi` joins (if using `CriteriaApi` for query building) or `JOIN FETCH` in case of `JPQL`.

Google gives a lot of examples on how-to. [Here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/) is one of them

Comment: Yes indeed, I hoped that there would be a built-in feature inside Hibernate that will permit the switch between eager and Lazy, but I'll do it with Criteria :-)

Thanks for your time !